# Alternative to Object Bar

Tags: windows-vista, software-rec, stardock

Does anybody know any alternatives to stardocks "ObjectBar", because if I use that, it stuffs up my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Samurize? It doesn't (by itself, anyway, there are other piece of software to do it) knock a bit off your screen, but you can certainly make always-on-top bars full of useful information, and interactive interactivity with it. Comes with a WYSIWYG editor, too, so it's easy to do things! Plenty of premade skins already exist on sites like DeviantArt, too.

Answer (score 0):

Winstep's Work-Shelf (part of **[WinStep Xtreme](http://www.winstep.net/index.asp?cat=winstep)**, but can be purchased separately) is probably as close as it gets:

> A powerful, multi-paged desktop
>   replacement, program launcher and
>   document organizer that can be used as
>   an alternative or supplement to the
>   normal Windows desktop. Also features
>   handy modules such as a talking clock
>   that can synchronize your system time
>   with the atomic time servers on the
>   Internet, an Email Checker, Weather
>   monitor, CPU, RAM and Net Meters and
>   more!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the top bar is all you want, try finderbar or winmac. Winmac is technically an older version of the Mac bar (the mac 9 bar) for Windows, and can be kinda buggy, though. Finderbar is always shareware, so you won't get bothered by objectdock sharewares` TRY NOW or BUY NOW pop-ups, but it doesn't work AS WELL on some computers. If it does work though, you should have a nice, complete OSX bar at the top of the screen.

If you are looking for a program that technically makes your PC a Mac without actually being one, try flyakite OSX. It comes with a theme that makes your startup, logon and desktop look like mac OSX Tiger (not quite sure, think its Tiger) it even says OSX! It also comes with a dock at the bottom, and bar at the top similar to finderbar, but better. Free, works with all versions of Windows, excluding 64 bits (they're working on that).